# Attaching handlers to respond to signals within objects in python

Tags: python

In javascript, if I have an object that contains a method that wants to send a signal to outside the object, I might do something like this ...

```
function class1(arg1){
    ...
    //something has happened - send out an alert
    this.method1();
    ...
}

var obj1 = new class1();

//define function to respond to the request from obj1 
obj1.method1 = function(){ ... }
```

Is there an equivalent way of doing this in python? (python 2).

Comment: I think blinker can give you what you need https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blinker

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a Method to an Existing Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object)

Comment: I dont want to add a method to an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in python.

```
class class1(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    def myevent(self):
        self.method1(self)
    def realmethod(self):
        print('arg', self.arg)

def eventhandler(obj):
    print('event')
    obj.realmethod()


>>> obj1 = class1('real object attr')
>>> obj1.method1 = eventhandler
>>> obj1.myevent()
event
('arg', 'real object attr')
```

As in javascript you want to make sure you set `method1` to be callable before it will be called.

**Edit**: updated code example to make sure you can pass `self` to `eventhandler` and use it just like in real method.

Comment: thanks very much, by the way, what so you call this kind of pattern?

Comment: @Marcin, you're right, but you always can pass `self` from `myevent` to `method1` if you need it there.

Comment: @Marcin, I dont want to create a method on the object. I.e. I dont want self to be passed. I just want to alert code outside the object that something has happened - obj1 does not deal with event it is up to code outside obj1

Comment: @Marcin, I did what you said. It works as I expected. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Maybe there is a more standard way of doing what i want then

Comment: @spiderplant0, I think what you are looking for is called Observer design pattern. However, this is a bad way to implement it.